# Slide out menu bar with click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

Exhausted in trying to figure out what is wrong. I can't seem to get my menu box to slide out.
https://jsfiddle.net/87cd9341/5/

My sliding menu box does not slide out when I click on the "nav-toggle".
Not sure if z-index has anything to do with it because I'm using it to cover some elements, but it shouldn't right?

I just added the main elements of the code...when you click the black tab, the blue box is suppose to shoot out right?

When I I manually add "open" into class for the "nav-side" into the html or input 0% into the transform section of the "nav-side" into the css, this is what I want to happen after I click the "nav-toggle' with jquery/javascript.

```
<div class="nav-side">
</div>
<div class="tab-container">
    <a href="#" class="nav-toggle"></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

.plageholder-container {
    display: block;
    width: 29.064039%;
    min-width: 121px;
    max-width: 121px;
    margin-left: 2.955665%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2.955665%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index:2;
    }

.nav-side {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29.064039%;
    height:121px;
    border-width:3px;
    min-width: 295px;
    max-width: 500px;   
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2.955665%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:1;
    margin-left: 2.955665%;
    padding-left: 120px;
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    transition: transform .06s ease;
}

.nav-side.open {
    transform:translateX(0);
}

.tab-container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 29.064039%;
    height:121px;
    border-width:3px;
    min-width: 25px;
    max-width: 25px;    
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2.955665%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 126px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ffffcc;
    z-index:0;
    margin-left: 2.955665%;
}

.nav-toggle{
    position: relative;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 3px;
    width:25px;
    height:121px;
    background-image: url(../Buttons/Button-About_Slider_Letter.svg);
}

$(".nav-toggle").on("click", function(){
$("nav-side").toggleClass("open");
});
```

});

Theoretically, if my research is correct I think `class="nav-side"` is suppose to change to `class="nav-side open"`
when I click the `"nav-toggle"` link ????????

Comment: provide the script

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably either the position or z-index. Please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/87cd9341/2/) Thanks for looking into this. The positions for the containers using the z-index all have fixed positions. https://jsfiddle.net/87cd9341/2/

Answer (score 0):

Missing a dot `.` in `$("nav-side")`

```
$(".nav-side").toggleClass("open");
```

Comment: your edit https://jsfiddle.net/87cd9341/8/ it show blue box after I click black tab, see [this gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f8D9.gif)